# Google Maps Autocomplete Box, listener on shift+enter

Tags: jquery, google-maps, autocomplete

I've researched this quite a bit and having found anything. I'm a newb programmer so then again maybe there is a solution and I did not really notice it.

I have a google places autocomplete box which I use for users to add places onto a google map.
Users can select down with arrows the intended place and press enter to add it.

What I want to do is to have the map pan to the location selected when the user presses shift+enter. I've tried but to no avail.

Here is the original listener to the autocomplete box:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autoCompleteBox, 'place_changed', onPlaceChanged);
```

Here is how I've been trying to edit it:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autoCompleteBox, 'place_changed', function(){
    if ($('#searchTextField').keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
            var place= autoCompleteBox.getPlace();
            _map.setCenter(place.getPosition()); 
            console.log("logged shift enter");
        }
     });
else {
    onPlaceChanged();
}
```

});

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your autoCompleteBox is an instance of google.maps.places.Autocomplete class, that object does not send any arguments to the event listener for the place_changed event, so your event object may only exist in Internet Explorer, (because in IE it is global). Beyond that, if the place has already changed and the place_changed event fired, then the user is no longer pressing any keys. If you want to use the information contained in the event object then you should build your own autoCompleteBox from scratch instead of using the one from the API. To be sure, try adding another `console.log("Fired")` in the first line of the function, before the if() statement.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Gonna try with that. And sorry I took a while to get back at it.

Comment: Never mind how long you took to get back at it, just feel free to up-vote and/or accept the answer, if you found it useful. :-)

Comment: Marcelo, I'm still trying to build one, would you have any example I could use to guide me? I'm looking at the jQuery autocomplete guidelines and the places API v3 reference, but well I'm getting stuck in getting it to work. All examples of jQuery autocomplete I find use geocoding, not the places API....

Comment: Ugh, this is an old post! I'm a bit lost about what you need. Does this example help? http://maps.forum.nu/v3/ac.html (US only) - If it doesn't just post a new question.

Comment: it's old but i've been trying since then!In the example, you're using the google autocomplete object. I'm trying to go about creating a jQuery autocomplete which source is the autocomplete, then fallsback onto geocoder. but we can focus on the autocomplete first. The point being I need to be able to get more advanced functionalities than the google autocomplete object. Namely being able to listen to other events that the on place changed. Thanks for your help!